Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out - Flutter Error
I have been working on this project for a while now just 4 days ago I tried to run the project and I keep getting this error. I have tried virtually everything but it is not running. I even tried to uninstall everything flutter and android studio and reinstall again but still the same issue persist can anyone help me out please? Meanwhile i can run other flutter project but this one never.

This is my dart verision:
mac@MACs-MacBook-Pro nicml_mobile % flutter --version
Flutter 3.19.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ba39319843 (6 months ago) • 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
Engine • revision 2e4ba9c6fb
Tools • Dart 3.3.1 • DevTools 2.31.1

And this is my pubspec.yaml:
name: wey_mobile
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.4+6

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.0
  provider: ^6.0.2
  oktoast: ^3.1.5
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^6.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.6
  intl: ^0.18.1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
  flutter_overlay_loader: ^2.0.0
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  flutter_smart_dialog: ^4.0.9+8
  animation_wrappers: ^3.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  flutter_animate: ^2.0.0
  freezed_annotation: ^2.2.0
  freezed: ^2.2.1
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.2
  riverpod_annotation: ^1.0.4
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.1.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  riverpod: ^2.2.0
  google_fonts: ^6.1.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  pinput: ^2.2.30
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2
  package_info_plus:
  sentry_flutter: ^7.12.0
  badges: ^3.1.2
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.6
  pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
  local_auth: ^2.1.7
  encrypt: ^5.0.3
  metamap_plugin_flutter: ^4.3.2
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutterwave_standard: ^1.0.8
  file_picker: ^6.1.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.5
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.2
  pdf: ^3.10.7
  image: ^4.1.4
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.1.2
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^24.1.45
  open_file: ^3.3.2
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.3.8
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.5.3+1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.10
  upgrader: ^9.0.0
  camera: ^0.10.5+9
  livechatt: ^1.4.0
  showcaseview: ^2.0.3
  move_to_background: ^1.0.2
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.7
  fancy_password_field: ^2.0.7
  tutorial_coach_mark: ^1.2.11
  screen_size_test: ^1.0.2+3
  device_preview: ^1.1.0
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  universal_html: ^2.2.4
  avatar_glow: ^3.0.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/launcher-icon.png
  color: "#ffffff"
  android: true
  ios: true


flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/launcher-icon.png"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/docs/
    - .env
    - .env.develop



Further screen shots of the output after running
flutter run --verbose



Honestly I have ran out of option on what to do I even tried to reclone the project from my repository still the same error persist. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

It seems like network connectivity issue.
Could you please run the app with Verbose enabled using flutter run --verbose command and share the screenshot ?

hi @albert I've added more screenshots
